# is it possible to track user position from his phone number in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, geocoding, core-location

I am working on map based iphone application. Where i need to find user position of week days from morning 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM either by using Device IDs or his mobile number. I know that Apple has instructed third-party developers to cease tracking iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch users via the unique serial number associated with each one of its hardware devices. But is it possible to track position from any other way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way is to use location based APIs. Device ID and MAC are deprecated and giving same results for iOS7.

It is not possible to track with mobile number as well. Service providers can help for that but not with help of phone.

Comment: @ApurvIt means that it can't be possible from app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can track a phone by the mobile number unless you are the police or something, and have access to that data.

Comment: I want to know whether it is possible or not for programmers apart from police? I am creating this application for ios enterprise program..

Comment: With the number, I doubt it, honestly. I would say no

Comment: Thanks alot for both answers Antonio..even i have searched we cant do this, even it's not permit by Apple. You are really very helping as well as funny guy....